# hazard increase

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I had a question regarding this proof. The hazard function is being defined as $\frac{\phi(x)}{1-F(x)}$ with $\phi(x)$ as the density function and $F(x)$ the CDF.
How can I prove that this is increasing in $x$ if we’re dealing with a normal distribution?

Comment: Ah, wow thanks so much! Do you know if this also holds for the hazard rate of the binomial distribution?

Comment: Oops, deleted my comment because I thought I had found a solution and was going to post an answer... the old comment said it suffices to show for $x_1\leq x_2$, you have $\frac{\phi(x_1)}{1-F(x_1)} \leq \frac{\phi(x_2)}{1-F(x_2)}$, i.e., $\phi(x_1)(1-F(x_2)) \leq \phi(x_2)(1-F(x_2))$. And since $1-F(x_2) \leq 1-F(x_1)$ always, it follows that the desired inequality holds when $\phi(x_1) \leq \phi(x_2)$ (which is true, for instance, if $x_1,x_2 \leq 0$). But I don't know how to extend this to all $x$.

Comment: It [doesn't appear this is true for the binomial distribution](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mjhsg5fozl), at least not for every choice of $n$ and $p$.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use differentiation:

Assuming that $\phi(x) $ is specified by the normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, we let:

$$ h(x) = \frac{\phi (x)}{ 1- F(x)} = \frac{\phi (x)}{ 1- \int_{-\infty} ^x \phi(t)dt}$$

Then:

\begin{align}
\frac{d h(x)}{d x} &= \frac{-\frac{(x-\mu)}{\sigma^2} \phi (x)}{ 1- \int_{-\infty} ^x \phi(t)dt} + \frac{(\phi(x))^2}{(1- \int_{-\infty} ^x \phi(t)dt)^2} \\
&=\Bigg[\frac{\phi (x)}{( 1- F(x))^2} \Bigg] \Big(\phi(x) - \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma^2} (1-F(x)) \Big)
\end{align}

Since the term in square brackets is always positive, We just need to focus on the term in the normal brackets (and show that it is always $>0$).

When $x \leq \mu$, it is clear that:

\begin{align}
\phi(x) - \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma^2} (1-F(x)) > 0
\end{align}

When $x> \mu$, it is not so straightforward. So let's do it step by step. We begin by looking at the second term in the expression:

\begin{align}
\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma^2} (1-F(x)) 
&= \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma^2}\int_x^\infty \phi(t)dt \\
&= \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma^2} \int_x^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} e^{-\frac{(t-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} dt\\
&< \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma^2} \int_x^\infty \frac{(t-\mu)/\sigma^2}{(x-\mu)/\sigma^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} e^{-\frac{(t-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dt \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \int_x^\infty \frac{t-\mu}{\sigma^2}e^{-\frac{(t-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} dt \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \Big[ -e^{-\frac{(t-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\Big]_x^\infty \\
&= \phi(x)
\end{align}

The inequality follows from the fact that the ratio $\frac{t-\mu}{x-\mu} > 1$.

Thus, from this, we see that when $x > \mu$ we have

\begin{align}
\phi(x) - \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma^2} (1-F(x)) > \phi(x) - \phi(x) = 0
\end{align}

So we can conclude that $$\frac{dh(x)}{dx} > 0$$ Which shows that $h(x)$ is an increasing function of $x$.

Comment: wow, thanks so much! Do you know if the hazard rate would also be increasing for a binomial distribution?

Comment: @NotSoSmart97 I think there was a comment on your original question that said it isn't. Hope you can accept/upvote if my answer helps (:

Comment: Hi, thanks yeah! Oh I didn't see that at first. And I did!

Comment: Hi Sean! I understood almost every part of your pure proof. There was only one thing where I couldn't  follow. When you derivated the hazard function first, how did you manage to get the first two equalities in order to get to the brackets?

Comment: I was a little terse - The first equality follows from the statement of the Fundamental Theorem of calculus: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus (First part) and the rest is just algebraic simplification. Btw I don't think you've accepted the answer haha :P

Comment: Oh thanks, sorry I forgot to answer! There was one more thing: Why is t-\mu /x-\mu>1? I get that it is greater equal to 1, but I didn't know why the strict inequality would hold

Comment: @NotSoSmart97 Notice the region of integration is over all values $t > x$. If $x > \mu$ then $x - \mu > 0$, and since $t > x$, it follows that $t - \mu > 0$. Since $t > x$, $t - \mu > x - \mu$, leading to $\frac{t-\mu}{x-\mu} > 1$ by division.

Answer (score 0):

First, for $x>0$,
$$
\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2/2}\,dt < \frac1x\int_x^\infty te^{-t^2/2}\,dt
= \frac1x e^{-x^2/2}.
$$
So, for a standard normal,
$$
\frac d{dx}\bigg(\frac{1-F(x)}{\phi(x)}\bigg)
= \frac d{dx}\bigg(e^{x^2/2}\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2/2}\,dt\bigg)
= xe^{x^2/2}\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2/2}\,dt - 1 < 0,
$$
for all $x$. (If $x\le 0$, the left-hand side is less than or equal to $-1$. If $x>0$, it follows from the initial inequality.)

Thus, $(1-F(x))/\phi(x)$ is decreasing, so the hazard function, $h(x)$, is increasing. Since the hazard function of a $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is $\sigma^{-1} h((x-\mu)/\sigma)$, the same is true for a general normal distribution.

Comment: Thanks so much for the formal proof!

Comment: There is one thing I don't quite understand: Why is t>x?

Comment: Because the integral is from $x$ to $\infty$, so inside that integral, the variable $t$ only takes on values in $(x,\infty)$.

Comment: Oh, I see thanks! So it is: $t \in (x,\infty)$, not $t \in [x,\infty)$ right?

Comment: It doesn't matter, since the integral over a single point is always zero.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course! Damn, can't think straight. Thanks so much!